# Algorithm for identifying "closed surfaces" in graph

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, surface

I have a drawing application where users can either create nodes or edges  by entering data (no "direct painting" with the cursor):

```
Node(double xpos, double ypos)
Edge(Node startNode, Node endNode)
```

Now, I am looking for an algorithm that identifies closed surfaces that are created by a user graph. By closed surface, I mean all areas that are completly enclosed by edges. As an example, the smallest possible surface would be a triangle with three nodes and three edges (1->2, 2->3, 3->1). Of course it can get more complicated, for example when multiple edges share a single node.

I am sure that there must be multiple algorithms for that, but so far my search efforts have not been successful (which could be because english is not my mother tongue and I'm not familiar with the specific vocabulary in this area). So any help to push me in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

The next step would be to have nested surfaces and all the combinations that are possible. I created an example picture but don't have enough rep to post it here, so this is the link: [example image with nested surfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iBmD.jpg). The image shows two rectangles which create three possible surfaces you could name AND (blue), OR (red) and XOR (green). Are there algorithms that are simple enough so implementing this won't turn into a computer science thesis? Or would you recommend switching to existing solutions?

Comment: Am I missing anything, or is a more common wording for the problem you are describing the finding of **cycles** in the graph?

Comment: The CS thesis for such things was written long ago; I imagine a useful approach would involve selecting a starting node and walking the graph from there. If you reach your starting point, the graph is cyclical. If not, but you run out of connecting nodes, it's acyclical. That kind of thing?

Comment: Are you looking to compute a [planar straight-line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_straight-line_graph) from a set of line segments?  If so, try starting with [Polygons generated by a set of segments](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/polygons-generated-by-a-set-of-segments) or [Polygon Detection from a Set of Lines](http://web.ist.utl.pt/alfredo.ferreira/publications/12EPCG-PolygonDetection.pdf).

Comment: OK, there was too much going on in my head at once, I see that I need to break down this problem into multiple steps. 1. Find closed cycles (thanks @O.R. and @Rob). 2. Find overlaps / nested polygons (PSLG reference looks promising @dbc). After that, I want to allow users to select existing polygons, so I need a) Point in Polygon algorithm and b) a way to "connect" the calculated polygons with my WPF Canvas for user interaction and highlighting. Long way to go ;)